# shear wave speeds and elastic anistropy

Tags: waves

Background: I am working with 2d tissue slices that are known to be elastically anisotropic as a result of different collagen fiber bundle orientations.

Question: I am interested in whether it is possible to use **ultrasonic shear wave velocity data** (focus of the push beam is at the centroid of the tissue slice..think point source in the middle) **to estimate collagen fiber bundle orientations**.

I am not sure if this the right forum for this type of question..but at least in the clinical ultrasound literature, I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right place either, but off the cuff, it seems possible to find the grain of your sample with this [phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_wave_splitting), where the "cracks" are the spaces between the collagen fibers and the pattern is an ellipsoidal wave with the short axis pointing along the bundle orientation, assuming a homogeneous distribution of bundle orientation.

Comment: My bad, I meant "long axis." I'm not a geologist qq

Edit: I just waved a sheet of paper around and now I think it's the short axis again.